# Visual Studio ADO .NET can't connect to mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I work on Windows Forms project in C# and I need to connect to mysql database (localhost:3306).
I use Entity framework 6.4.0 and .NET Connector 8.0.18. 
When I go to Project -> Add New Item -> Data -> ADO .NET Entity Model and go to Code First from database -> New Connection , my Choose Data Source Dialog haven't option for MYSQL DATABASE
[image]

I have Mysql Workbench 8.0 and I connected to database.

When I click on other option I have dialog:

[image]

Can't find database to select.
Where is the problem?

Comment: what if you select <other> option?

Comment: I update my question in case when I select <other>...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that case, it normally happens when you install visual studio after installation of  MySQL. Try re-installing MYSQL then it will have to work.

**Note:** Ensure backing up all your databases first

Happy programming.